# Append to environment variable in LLDB

Tags: debugging, lldb

It is relatively easy to set environment variables in LLDB, via

```
settings set target.env-vars DEBUG=1
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to *append* to an environment variable.  The following doesn't work:

```
(lldb) settings set target.env-vars DEBUG=1
(lldb) settings set target.env-vars DEBUG=2$DEBUG
(lldb) settings show target.env-vars DEBUG
target.env-vars (dictionary of strings) =
  DEBUG=2$DEBUG
```

Comment: More traditionally you'd be able to set variables when invoking lldb itslef and have them inherited, but apparently on Mac system integrity protection now resets the environment when invoking lldb...

Answer (score 1):

Referencing variables with `$` only works in the shell or if the program specifically supports it. You simply have to paste or type the old value manually.

Possibly you can use [Python scripting](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/python.html)  to read and write the environment variables.